# typecasting a pointer to a multidimensional array in C

Tags: c

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int a[5][10][2];
int *p;
p = (int(*)[10][2])p;//Gives error!
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I want to type cast p to type so that it can act as a pointer to the given 3-d array?Is there a way to do so.I am applyindg the idea that the type of a variable is everything except variable name.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you trying to "typecast" anything? Why would you expect a value "typecasted" to `(int(*)[10][2])` to be compatible with an `int *` pointer? And why does your original code assigns `p` to `p`, completely ignoring `a`?

This is what you can do

```
int a[5][10][2];
int (*p)[10][2] = a;
```

Now `p` is a pointer that can be used to access `a`, i.e. `p[i][j][k]` is equivalent to `a[i][j][k]`. No typecasting necessary.

Comment: "Why would you expect that a value "typecasted" to (int(*)[10][2]) can be placed into an int * pointer?"why not ?arent both of them will have the same size?

Comment: @user2688772: The language does not care about "size". "Size" does not matter. What does matter is the rules of type compatibility described in the language specification. And these rules say that `int(*)[10][2]` and `int *` are two completely different, incompatible pointer types.

Comment: The dimensions seem messed up; shouldn't it be `int (*)[5][10]`? I am not 100% sure.

Comment: @anatolyg: No. The first dimesion is always the only one that is "flexible" and can be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

If you write p = (int(*)[10][2])a; it won't give you any errors, may be a warning. You are thinking that p will be converted to pointer to a 3-D array, which is wrong. Try this statement after assigning a to p.

```
printf("addresses %u   %u",p,p+1);
```

According to you, output should be something similar to this(lets say) "addresses 9990000 99940000", because you are thinking p is pointing to 3-D array. However you will get similar to "addresses 9990000 9990004", proving that p is a pointer to an integer.